# RSA Crypto Service Container Private Key goes out of sync

Tags: c#, .net, cryptoapi, rsacryptoserviceprovider

In a client/server model
We have a RSACryptoServiceProvider key created using a well known "container name" at the startup code, and set a rule on it to Allow Generic Read, and persist the public key into a database. The clients connecting to the server, send sensitive information encrypted with the public key and the server decrypts it using the private key.

However, over time, we are observing that the public key in the crypto store (it's a machine level crypto store at %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\Machine Keys goes out of sync with the stored public key in the database) and our clients stop communicating with the server.

Are there any possible reasons as to how this happens ? Is there a way we can detect it when this happens ?

Comment: That sounds strange. Are you absolutely sure it isn't in fact the public key that the clients have that no longer matches the public key on the server?

Comment: The clients have it from the database, the server uses it from the crypto store.